# How to input a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I was going through a solution to a problem which printed the inner and outer array. But while going the solution I was not able to understand the first line in which they took the input. I'm not able to get why they have used int there. The syntax is quite confusing to me. Here is the code:

```
A,B = [np.array([input().split()],int) for _ in range(2)]
print(np.inner(A,B)[0][0],np.outer(A,B),sep="\n")
```

Comment: ```int``` is the dtype specifiying the type of the array. It's the second argument to the np.array() constructor function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage for numpy.array is numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)

All of the named parameters in the form "name"="something" are optional. In that example they are using numpy.array(List, dtype) where the list is the split input and dtype (which stands for data type) is int or integer.

So all [np.array([input().split()],int) does is splits user input (which is input()) into a list and tells numpy to store that as a numpy.array of Integers (rather than strings or floats)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the first line is a [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) that builds a list of numpy arrays where each array contains an int